# Asterisk queue_log Caller ID in Abandon Event

Tags: asterisk

Please help me, I would like to see the caller ID against the Abandon event in queue_log. I have looked at creating an additional info, but I honestly dont know where to look at for making the changes. My current queue logs show following results.

```
1409583936|1409583936.4|100|NONE|ENTERQUEUE||5001|1
1409583942|1409583936.4|100|Jeet|CONNECT|6|1409583936.5|5
1409583944|1409583936.4|100|Jeet|COMPLETECALLER|6|2|1
1409583970|1409583970.8|100|NONE|ENTERQUEUE||5001|1
1409583995|1409583970.8|100|Jeet|RINGNOANSWER|25000
1409584005|1409583970.8|100|NONE|ABANDON|1|1|35
```

Please help me....
Thanks..
Jeet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have callerid on EnterQueue event.

So you have remmeber that or on abandodn do lookup in past for such event.

It is unlikly you can get callerid on abandon, looks like that require complex code rewrite.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! This is what I have exactly done after reading your comment. Did 2 queries in php loop and then fetched the results.

Thanks a lot :)